# guardar latitud y longitud por distancia (Google Maps y Ionic 3)

Tags: javascript, ionic, google-maps

Tengo la siguiente función  para guardar guardar latitud y longitud  en firebase, pero veo que lo guarda muy rapido, es decir, aproximadamente en 20 minutos guardo alrededor de 400 posiciones.

```
    //empieza geololaizacion
start() {
    let markes = [];
   // Compruebo si esta habilidata la opcion de localizacion
  this.backgroundGeolocation.isLocationEnabled()
  .then((activado) =>{
      //si esta activado
    if(activado){

      let config = {
        desiredAccuracy: 0,
        stationaryRadius: 0,
        distanceFilter: 0,
        debug: false,
        interval: 1000
      };
      //Geolocalizacion en segundo Plano      
      this.backgroundGeolocation
      .configure(config)
      .subscribe((location) => {
        console.log("latitud actualizacion background 1"+location.latitude);

        this.zone.run(() => {
        this.lat = location.latitude;
        this.lng = location.longitude;
        });
        this.actuario.update({
            lat: location.latitude,
            lng: location.longitude
        });
           markes.push({
             latitud:location.latitude,
             longitud:location.longitude
           });
           this.actuario.set({markes}, { merge: true })
                   .then(function() {})
                   .catch(function(error) {
                   console.log("Error al subir datos! " + error);
             });


        });

      // empieza actualizacion si se sale de la aplicacion
      this.backgroundGeolocation.start();
      let options = {
        frequency: 3000,
        enableHighAccuracy: true
    };
        //cuando la aplicacion esta abierta y activada
      this.watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition(options).filter((p: any) => p.code === undefined)
      .subscribe((position: Geoposition) => {
        console.log("latitud actualizacion 2"+position.coords.latitude + "  " + position.coords.longitude);
       //actualizo dato en firebase
        this.actuario.update({
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
          });
          //para poder mapear en un mapa se guardan los datos
             markes.push({
               latitud:position.coords.latitude,
               longitud:position.coords.longitude
             });
             this.actuario.set({markes}, { merge: true })
                     .then(function() {})
                     .catch(function(error) {
                     console.log("Error al subir datos! " + error);
               });
      });

    }else {
      this.backgroundGeolocation.showLocationSettings();
    }
  }) 
}
```

La primera opcion es guardar esas latitudes y longitudes por 3 metros, o guardar los datos cada 5 minutos, Hay alguna configuracion con google maps para hacer esto ?,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según [la documentación que aparece en el repositorio](https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation), la configuración que le estás pasando:

```
 let config = {
    desiredAccuracy: 0,
    stationaryRadius: 0,
    distanceFilter: 0,
    debug: false,
    interval: 1000
  };
```

Tiene dos efectos. Primero: `interval: 1000` significa actualizar cada un segundo. Según la documentación:

> **interval:** **(sólo en Android)** The minimum time interval between location updates in milliseconds. @see Android docs for more
>   information.

Si guardaste 400 posiciones en 20 minutos significa que estás actualizando cada 3 segundos. Esto se debe a que la geolocalización del dispositivo o del browser no puede responder más rápido que eso.

Si pusieras en cambio `interval: 300000` estarías actualizando cada 5 minutos.

El segundo efecto es que pones `stationaryRadius: 0` o sea, aunque la persona no se haya movido respecto de su ubicación anterior, gatillas el evento de almacenar la posición igual. Acorde a la documentación:

> **stationaryRadius:** Stationary radius in meters. When stopped, the minimum distance the device must move beyond the stationary location
>   for aggressive background-tracking to engage.

Si pusieras en cambio `stationaryRadius: 10` sólo gatillarías el evento si la persona se ha movido al menos 10 metros desde la última consulta.

Aparentemente esto último requiere un setting adicional en iOS (para forzar el uso del modo FOREGROUND), por lo que si no te resulta podrías probar también usando `distanceFilter`. Tú tienes este parámetro en cero, lo cual, de nuevo, implica que siempre estás gatillando la petición que almacena la posición. Si pusieras en cambio `distanceFilter:10`, lo harías sólo si la persona se ha movido al menos 10 metros. **PEEERO** la documentación dice:

> **distanceFilter**: The minimum distance (measured in meters) a device must move horizontally before an update event is generated.

Suena raro que sólo detecte la posición en la coordenada X, pero igual pruébalo.

**Resumen:**

Juega con los parámetros aumentando `stationaryRadius`, `distanceFilter` e `interval` hasta que obtengas la frecuencia deseada. Yo empezaría con `stationaryRadius` que pareciera funcionar tanto en iOS como en Android y suena como una restricción bastante sensata.

PD: Nunca he usado esta librería y hace 5 años que no uso Ionic. Sólo me leí la documentación.